# What is compressed memory expressed as in relation to memory?

Tags: macos, memory, top

Compressed memory is obviously memory that is compressed to save space, but the macOS utility Activity Monitor and the UNIX utility `top` are ambiguous about what compressed memory is expressed as in relation to memory. That is, is it the amount of space the compressed memory takes up? Is it the amount of memory that was compressed? Does the memory usage (i.e. "Memory" in Activity Monitor, "MEM" in `top`) include or exclude the amount of compressed memory? I think [and/or hope] you get what I'm getting at here.

Also, do Activity Monitor and `top` differ in the way they represent memory and compressed memory?